# Input Validation redundancy

Tags: python, validation, python-3.x, exception

I'm working on input validation with exception handling and my code works but it prints error messages twice and I can't figure out how to make the validation loop to just print one of the error messages not both.

This is my code:

```
def main():
    low = 0
    high = 10
    get_num_in_range(low,high)

def get_num_in_range (low,high):
    prompt = 'Enter a number between: ' + str(low) + ' and ' + str(high) + ': '
    answer = low-1 #just get me in to loop
    while answer < low or answer > high:
        try:
            answer = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid data type!')
        if answer < low or answer > high:
            print('Invalid!')
    return answer

main()
```

the output looks like this:

> Enter a number between: 0 and 10: a
>
> Invalid data type!
>
> Invalid!
>
> Enter a number between: 0 and 10:

How do I get the loop to only print the relevant error message?

EDIT: SOLVED HA! I'm an idiot I had the 'if' validation outside the exception handler.
fixed code:

```
while answer < low or answer > high:
    try:
        answer = int(input(prompt))
            if answer < low or answer > high:
                print('Invalid!')
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid data type!')
return answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option could be to look at the try-except-else clause (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

```
while answer < low or answer > high:
    try:
        answer = int(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid data type!')
    else:
        if answer < low or answer > high:
            print('Invalid!')
```

The else clause gets called when no exception is caught

Comment: oh i didn't know about that. I'm taking a very basic intro course so that's not a surprise. I'll keep that in mind down the line. thank you!